# Reading resource txt line by line

Tags: c#, resources, .net-assembly

Had a txt file on my desktop with code:

```
string source = @"C:\Users\Myname\Desktop\file.txt"
string searchfor = *criteria person enters*
foreach (string content in File.ReadLines(source))
{
if (content.StartsWith(searchfor)
{
*do stuff*
}
}
```

I recently just learned I can add the txt as a resource file (as it will never be changed). However, I cannot get the program to read that file.txt as a resource line by line like above. I have tried 
    `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("WindowsFormsApplication.file.txt")`

with a stream reader but it says invalid types.

Basic concept: user enters data, turned into a string, compared to the starting line of the file.txt as it reads down the list.

Any help?

**edit**
Jon, I tried as a test to see if it is even reading the file:

```
        var assm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        using (var stream = assm.GetManifestResourceStream("WindowsFormsApplication.file.txt")) ;
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    label1.Text = line;
                }
            }
        }
```

It says "The name stream does not exist in the current context" and "Possible Mistaken Empty Statement" for the stream = assm.Get line

Comment: "it says invalid types" isn't very descriptive. Please show the *exact* code that failed, and the *exact* error message.

Comment: "System.IO.StreamReader" is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

Comment: Sorry I am extremely new to adding things to resources. I am not sure what the correct code even is to read such a file

Comment: Well you've got the code to open the stream - the problem is what you're doing with it, and you haven't shown the code which is failing. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-checklist

Comment: string result = StreamReader(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("WindowsFormsApplication2.file.txt"));

Comment: Right, that should be in the question. So it looks like you're trying to call `StreamReader` like a method, when you should be *constructing* one with the `new` operator... and that doesn't return a `string`, so you'd still get a type failure. See my answer for the code you want.

Comment: Apologies, I have tried numerous tutorials and my code is a bit messed up at this point. I've tried at least 20 variations I have seen online but nothing seems to work. I am not even sure what the code to put down even is. I will re-edit with some of the variations

Comment: It feels like the problems here are really to do with C# itself, not assembly resources etc. I suggest you try really hard to understand *every* error you see, before you move onto the next attempt.

Comment: I have re-edited with your code. As i stated before I am new to programming and everything I read says if I have a file that doesn't change but is used by the program to load it as a resource then use assembly and streamreader to call the data. Every tutorial I use seems to give me "invalid type" errors or "this doesnt exist in it's current context" despite being clearly labeled. My needs are different than the tutorials and I just dont understand what the system is actually doing to correct it.

Comment: If you're getting errors, that's to do with how you're using C# - you should read the code and errors really carefully, and make sure you understand it all. (If you haven't got a good C# book/tutorial, I'd get one now. Don't try to skip past it just to get something working - it will cost you time overall.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance. I found the issue was with the embedded resources and the location of the resources, which is why my code failed every time despite all the tutorials saying namespace.file when that is not the default visual studio location. Using your variation I was able to fully fix the issue! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `TextReader` to read a line at a time - and `StreamReader` is a `TextReader` which reads from a stream. So:

```
var assm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
using (var stream = assm.GetManifestResourceStream("WindowsFormsApplication.file.txt"))
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

You could write an extension method on `TextReader` to read all the lines, but the above is simpler if you only need this once.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue:

The file, while loaded as a resource, despite all the tutorials saying it is NameSpace.File, the truth is the system puts the location as NameSpace.Resources.File, so I had to update that as well.

Then I used the following code:

```
        string searchfor = textBox1.Text
        Assembly assm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        using (Stream datastream = assm.GetManifestResourceStream("WindowsFormsApplication2.Resources.file1.txt"))
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(datastream))
        {
            string lines;
            while ((lines = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (lines.StartsWith(searchfor))
                {
                    label1.Text = "Found";
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    label1.Text = "Not found";
                }
            }
        }
```